# Why can't I add a new canvas without messing up my project in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

So I'm working on this project in tKinter and I'm adding a series of frames and canvas to my notebook widget. I added all of them in the same way and the program is doing ok, but when I add the last one everything is messed up. This is how the program looks without the last frame:
[image: YES]

And this is how it looks with the last frame:
[image: NO]

This is my code:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

in_editor = False

root1 = tk.Tk()
root1.resizable(0, 0)
root1.title("Project Dragonfly")

plus_image = Image.open("Media/plus.png")
x_image = Image.open("Media/x.png")
expand_image = Image.open("Media/Expand.png")
retract_image = Image.open("Media/Retract.png")

x_image = x_image.resize((30, 30), Image.ANTIALIAS)
plus_image = plus_image.resize((30, 30), Image.ANTIALIAS)
expand_image = expand_image.resize((30, 30), Image.ANTIALIAS)
retract_image = retract_image.resize((30, 30), Image.ANTIALIAS)

x_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(x_image)
plus_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(plus_image)
expand_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(expand_image)
retract_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(retract_image)

room_frame_number = 0
rooms_frame_list = []
room_entries_list = []
room_names_list = []

item_frame_number = 0
items_frame_list = []

key_frame_number = 0
keys_frame_list = []

door_frame_number = 0
doors_frame_list = []

sequence_frame_number = 0
sequences_frame_list = []


def set_location(event):
    global loc_entry
    root1.folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=r"C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop")
    loc_entry.configure(state="normal")
    loc_entry.delete(0, "end")
    loc_entry.insert(-1, root1.folder_selected)
    loc_entry.configure(state="disabled")


def duplicated_file():
    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Ya existe un proyecto con este título.")


def enter_editor():
    def create_scrollbar(frame, canvas, second_frame):
        def adjust_scrollregion(event):
            canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

        my_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
        my_scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
        canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

        second_frame.bind("<Configure>", adjust_scrollregion)

    global room_frame_number

    root1.resizable(0, 0)
    root1.geometry("1100x800")

    title = title_entry.get()
    author = author_entry.get()
    path = loc_entry.get()

    main_Frame.destroy()

    editor_frame = tk.Frame(root1)
    editor_frame.pack()

    try:
        os.mkdir(path + "/{}".format(title))
        path = path + "/{}/game_data.py".format(title)
        file = open(path, "w")
        file.write("Author = " + author + "\n")
        file.write("Title = " + title + "\n\n")
    except FileExistsError:
        duplicated_file()

    root1.title("Project Dragonfly - " + title + ", por " + author)

    my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(root1)
    my_notebook.pack()

    width = 1100

    info_frame = ttk.Frame(my_notebook, width=width, height=800)
    rooms_frame = ttk.Frame(my_notebook, width=width, height=800)
    items_frame = ttk.Frame(my_notebook, width=width, height=800)
    keys_frame = ttk.Frame(my_notebook, width=width, height=800)
    doors_frame = ttk.Frame(my_notebook, width=width, height=800)
    sequences_frame = ttk.Frame(my_notebook, width=width, height=800)

    info_frame.grid_propagate(0)
    rooms_frame.grid_propagate(0)
    items_frame.grid_propagate(0)
    keys_frame.grid_propagate(0)
    doors_frame.grid_propagate(0)
    sequences_frame.grid_propagate(0)

    info_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    rooms_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    items_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    keys_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    doors_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    sequences_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

    my_notebook.add(info_frame, text="Información")
    my_notebook.add(rooms_frame, text="Habitaciones")
    my_notebook.add(items_frame, text="Objetos")
    my_notebook.add(keys_frame, text="Llaves")
    my_notebook.add(doors_frame, text="Puertas")
    my_notebook.add(sequences_frame, text="Secuencias")

    info_canvas = tk.Canvas(info_frame)
    info_canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=1)

    rooms_canvas = tk.Canvas(rooms_frame)
    rooms_canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=1)

    items_canvas = tk.Canvas(items_frame)
    items_canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=1)

    keys_canvas = tk.Canvas(keys_frame)
    keys_canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=1)

    doors_canvas = tk.Canvas(doors_frame)
    doors_canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=1)

    #sequences_canvas = tk.Canvas(sequences_frame)
    #sequences_canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=1)

    info_second_frame = tk.Frame(info_canvas)
    info_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=info_second_frame, width=width, anchor="nw")

    rooms_second_frame = tk.Frame(rooms_canvas, width=width)
    rooms_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=rooms_second_frame, width=width, anchor="nw")

    items_second_frame = tk.Frame(items_canvas, width=width)
    items_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=items_second_frame, width=width, anchor="nw")

    keys_second_frame = tk.Frame(keys_canvas, width=width)
    keys_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=keys_second_frame, width=width, anchor="nw")

    doors_second_frame = tk.Frame(doors_canvas, width=width)
    doors_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=doors_second_frame, width=width, anchor="nw")

    #sequences_second_frame = tk.Frame(sequences_canvas, width = width)
    #sequences_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=sequences_second_frame, width=width, anchor="nw")

    create_scrollbar(info_frame, info_canvas, info_second_frame)
    create_scrollbar(rooms_frame, rooms_canvas, rooms_second_frame)
    create_scrollbar(items_frame, items_canvas, items_second_frame)
    create_scrollbar(keys_frame, keys_canvas, keys_second_frame)
    create_scrollbar(doors_frame, doors_canvas, doors_second_frame)
    #create_scrollbar(sequences_frame, sequences_canvas, sequences_second_frame)


main_Frame = tk.LabelFrame(root1)
main_Frame.pack()

create_project_label = tk.Label(main_Frame, text="CREAR NUEVO PROYECTO", font=("Trajan", 22), anchor="w", width=23,
                                height=1)
title_label = tk.Label(main_Frame, text="TÍTULO: ", font=("Arial", 13), anchor="w", width=14, height=1, pady=5)
loc_label = tk.Label(main_Frame, text="LOCALIZACIÓN: ", font=("Aharoni", 13), anchor="w", width=14, height=1, pady=5)
author_label = tk.Label(main_Frame, text="AUTOR: ", font=("Aharoni", 13), anchor="w", width=14, height=1, pady=5)

button_frame = tk.Frame(main_Frame, pady=16)
ok_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Aceptar", width=10, command=enter_editor)
button_separator = tk.Label(button_frame, width=10)
cancel_buton = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Cancelar", width=10, command=root1.destroy)

title_entry = tk.Entry(main_Frame, width=42)

loc_entry = tk.Entry(main_Frame, width=42, state="disabled")

author_entry = tk.Entry(main_Frame, width=42)

create_project_label.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=4)

title_label.grid(column=0, row=2)
title_entry.grid(column=1, row=2)

loc_label.grid(column=0, row=3)
loc_entry.grid(column=1, row=3)

author_label.grid(column=0, row=4)
author_entry.grid(column=1, row=4)

button_frame.grid(column=0, row=5, columnspan=3, padx=20)
ok_button.grid(column=0, row=0)
button_separator.grid(column=1, row=0)
cancel_buton.grid(column=2, row=0)

loc_entry.bind("<1>", set_location)

root1.mainloop()
```

What am I doing wrong? The parts that mess up the program are the commentaries (starting with #).

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a smaller example. It would be particularly useful if you remove the images.

Comment: I wonder why the notebook fills all the space (the first image) **without** using `my_notebook.pack(fill='both', expand=1)`.  I expect that the second image is the correct output of your code.

Comment: There's so much duplicated code that could be replaced with a loop.  Using a loop would make this code much easier to debug. Also, you call `grid_propagate(0)` on the frames, but then you use `pack` to place objects in the frames.  My recommendation would be to use a loop and classes to create the tabs since they are all identical as far as I can tell.